# HTCondor: In the submit file, how to evaluate the value of a variable in order to write it in an output file name?

Tags: condor

I want to run several jobs with HTCondor, here is my submit file:

```
# Unix submit description file
b1=50+($(Process)%41)*10    
executable              = PATH/script.sh
arguments               = $(b1)
log                     = fit_it_data_$(b1).log
output                  = outfile_fit_$(b1).txt
error                   = errors_fit_$(b1).txt
transfer_input_files    = PATH
should_transfer_files   = Yes
when_to_transfer_output = ON_EXIT
queue 81
```

So my executable file is taking `b1` in argument, which is defined by a function of `$(Process)`. I want to write the value of `b1` in my output files. The problem is that I obtain something like that:

```
outfile_fit_50+17%41_100.txt
```

Even when I try to define `b1=$(50+($(Process)%41)*10)` I am getting the same...Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in a HTCondor submit file for evaluating a classad expression is "$$([ expression ]) ".  So, if you change your submit file to

```
output = output_file.$$([$(b1)])
```

I think you'll get what you want.  If you need to, you could put the same thing in the arguments command as well.